# How do I prove that a filter converges in a cartesian product?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, filters, product-space

I have the following problem:

> Let $\{(M_i, \mathfrak{M}_i)\}$ be nonempty topopological spaces. And let $M=\prod_{i\in I} M_i$. Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be a filter on $M$ and so $\mathfrak{F}_i=(\pi_i)_* \mathfrak{F}$ it's image filter on each $\mathfrak{M}_i$ ($\pi_i$ is the projection). I need to show that $\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p\in M$ iff $\mathfrak{F}_i$ converges to $p_i=\pi_i(p)$.

My Idea was the following:

*$\Rightarrow$ Let us assume that $\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p\in M$. Let us remark that $M$ is endowed with the product topology. Then we know by it's definition that all the projections $$\pi_i:M\rightarrow M_i$$are continuous for all $i\in I$. Now we have a continuous function $\pi_i$ and a convergent filter $\mathfrak{F}$ and this implies by a corollary of the lecture that $(\pi_i)_*\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $\pi_i(p)$ for all $i\in I$.*

Is this correct so far? So in the other direction I had some problems, I wanted to prove this by contradiction and that's what I get so far:

*$\Leftarrow$ Let us assume that $(\pi_i)_*\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p_i$ and that $\mathfrak{F}$ does not converge to $p$. By definition since $\mathfrak{F}$ does not converge to $p$ we know that $\mathfrak{F}$ is coarser that the the neighbourhood filter $\mathfrak{U}(p)$ of $p$, i.e. there exists a neighbourhood $U\in \mathfrak{U}(p)$ such that $U\notin \mathfrak{F}$. On the other hand since  $(\pi_i)_*\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p_i$ we know that the following inclusion holds: $$\mathfrak{U}(p_i)\subset (\pi_i)_*\mathfrak{F}=\{B\subset M_i: \exists A\in \mathfrak{F}\,\,\text{with}\,\,\pi_i(A)\subset B\}$$...*

Now I wanted to work with this explicit $U$ to produce a contradiction but I somehow don't see how. The only thing I remarked in addition is that for $V\in \mathfrak{U}(p_i)\Rightarrow \pi_i^{-1}(V)\in \mathfrak{U}(p)$ since $\pi_i$ are continuous.

Could someone maybe tell me if $\Rightarrow$ direction works and give me a hint for the other one how to create a contradiction?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward direction is fine, using the continuity of the projections.

For the reverse, we have a point $p = (p_i)_{i \in I}$ from the component spaces and we want to show that $\mathfrak{F}$ converges to $p$. We don't have to use contradiction, but use the standard base of the product topology: a basic open subset $B$ of $p$ is of the form $B=\bigcap_{i \in F} \pi_i^{-1}[O_i]$ where $O_i \subseteq M_i$ is open and contains $p_i$ and $F \subseteq I$ is finite.

Now show that all $\pi_i^{-1}[O_i] \in \mathfrak{F}$ from the fact that the "component filters" $(\pi_i)_\ast(\mathfrak{F})$ converge to $p_i$ for all $i$. Then the filter axioms tell us that $B \in \mathfrak{F}$ and as this holds for *all* basic open subsets of $p$, we have that $\mathfrak{U}(p) \subseteq \mathfrak{F}$ and so $\mathfrak{F} \to p$.

Comment: hello, thanks for the fast answer. Sorry I was stuck at the point where you use the standart base of the product topology. So if I remember correctly we know that the set $$S=\{\pi_i^{-1}(O_i):O_i\in \mathfrak{M}_i\}$$ is a subbasis, but then we need to take all finite intersections of elements to get a basis and then the arbitrary unions, or maybe I don't get this correclty

Comment: could you maybe explain this point again please? so for me it's clear why our subbasis looks like this, and I also know that if we take all finite intersections of elements of the subbasis then I get a basis. But this only means that each element of the topology can be written as unions of elements of the basis, in our case as unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$

Comment: @aprozz That's right, hence the finite intersection (over $i \in F$) that gives the base generated by this subbase. All other open sets are indeed unions (hence supersets of basic sets).

Comment: but why exaclty don't we need to take the union to get $B$

Comment: @aprozz So for any open set that contains $p$ we have finitely many subbasis sets of the form $\pi_i^{-1}[O_i]$ so that their intersection contains $p$ (so $p_i \in O_i$ must hold) and sits inside $O$.

Comment: @aprozz No, the unions are to get all *open* sets, the intersections are the base.

Comment: hmm okei but our definition says that a set $\mathfrak{B}$ is called a basis of $\tau$ if every element of $\tau$ is a union of elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ and in our case $\mathfrak{B}$ is the finite intersection of elements of $S$. Sorry I always had problems in understanding this basis-subbasis thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132974/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-aprozz).